# Channel Form - Submit via Ajax with file upload

Tags: channel-form, ajax

How do I implement an Ajax implementation on a Channel Form, especially when there is a file needed to be uploaded?

I look at an [example](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/examples.html), but I don't think I really understand how it works.

Comment: Could you be more descriptive? What about it don't you understand? I've personally implemented the example on the docs and it worked splendidly. Are you including `jquery.form.js`?

Comment: The example here only shows text inputs. What happens if I have a file input?

Comment: It's exactly the same. No alterations are needed. Below is an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this and it works just fine. Be sure to include the `title` input with valid data. If you're still having trouble, be sure to check the console log `data` object. If you dig around you'll probably find the pertinent error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
{exp:channel:form channel="your_channel" json="yes"}
    <input id="title" name="title" />
    {field:your_file_upload_channel_field}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
{/exp:channel:form}

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/jquery.form.js"></script>
{!-- jquery.form.js can be found at http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js --}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#publishForm').ajaxForm({
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    // success!
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, because you didn't specify, be sure you're using an instance of EE that supports Channel Form instead of Safecracker. I just checked the docs to 2.7.3 and it looks like files upload in Channel Form were included in 2.7.*.

> The File fieldtype is now compatible with Channel Form.

So if you have an instance that's older, file upload via channel form might not work.